# Very slow query when using CONNECT BY LEVEL

Tags: sql, oracle

**NEEDS**

I want to create a table like the following in Oracle SQL:

```
COUNTRY  NAME  WMWHSE_ID   DATE
   US     CRD2     1      040620
   GR     WAZ      2      040620
   CN     KOL      3      040620
   FR     DEL      4      040620
                  ...      ...
   US     CRD2     1      030620
   GR     WAZ      2      030620
   CN     KOL      3      030620
   FR     DEL      4      030620
                  ...      ...
```

Every warehouse in WMWHSE_ID will be printed with a DATE column for today's date, and this will be repeated for DATE = yesterday, the day before yesterday, the day before that...etc until exactly 1 week ago.
I have 124 warehouses total, so 124*7 = 868 rows total.

===

**QUERY BLOCK**

The following is my query. It uses the CONNECT BY LEVEL <= to achieve the 7 dates (in theory)

```
select 
SUBSTR(db_alias, 1, 2) AS COUNTRY, 
db_alias as NAME, 
To_Number(Regexp_Replace(Db_Logid, '[^0-9]', '')) As Wmwhse_Id, 
to_char(sysdate, 'yyyyMMdd')+1-level as ACTDATE 
from wmsadmin.pl_db, dual where db_alias not like '%BPV' and  db_alias not like 'PRDO%' and db_alias not like 'ENTERPRISE'
connect by level <=7
order by ACTDATE desc, WMWHSE_ID asc
```

(The GROUP BY is needed, because without it the table looks like:)

```
COUNTRY  NAME  WMWHSE_ID   DATE
   US     CRD2     1      040620
   GR     WAZ      2      040620
   CN     KOL      3      040620
   FR     DEL      4      040620
                  ...      ...
   US     CRD2     1      030620
   US     CRD2     1      030620
   US     CRD2     1      030620
   US     CRD2     1      030620
                  ...      ...
```

===

**THE ISSUE**

The query time seems to grow exponentially with n in CONNECT BY LEVEL <= n. I ran some testing and got the following:

```
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= n      ROWS         SECONDS
         1                 124           2-6
         2                 248           10+?
         3                 372           110
```

Anything n=4 and up seems to just hang sqldeveloper completely. When n=7, I left the computer running for 30+ minutes and the query was still running.

What is causing this slowness? Is there a better way to go about implementing my table? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is query so slow? Because each iteration connects each row with 124 new rows. So at second level it is 124 * 124 rows, at fourth level you get 236421376 rows, at seventh level 450766669594624 rows. This is why you get duplicates. Also join with dual has no impact.

The solution is to correct `connect by` part, add condition `wmwhse_id = prior wmwhse_id`:

```
select country, name, wmwhse_id, trunc(sysdate) - level + 1 dt
  from pl_db 
  connect by level <= 7 and prior wmwhse_id = wmwhse_id and prior sys_guid() is not null 
  order by dt desc, wmwhse_id
```

It is even easier with recursive CTE, which is standard in most databases:

```
with r(country, name, wmwhse_id, dt, lvl) as (
  select country, name, wmwhse_id, trunc(sysdate), 1 from pl_db union all
  select country, name, wmwhse_id, trunc(sysdate) - lvl, lvl + 1 from r where lvl < 7)
select country, name, wmwhse_id, dt from r;
```

But simplest is to make cross join with 7 numbers, doesn't matter how you generate them:

```
select country, name, wmwhse_id, trunc(sysdate) - trim(column_value) + 1 dt
  from pl_db cross join xmltable('1 to 7')
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=127a412d7c7e382a9559f709e0074341) containing all three queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot, turns out cross join was the most straightforward solution for my use case but the other 2 methods prove useful as well, with all 3 performing more or less at the same speed.  :: A note about recursive CTE in Oracle is that the recursive element/"variable" is always "post-incremented" as you'd call it in other programming languages - it doesn't matter if 'lvl +1' is specified before or after the 'trunc(sysdate)'. Just something I was curious about when using the query.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from being slow, your query returned many duplicates. Even if you select distinct values, it won't be any faster.

But, something like this might. I don't have your data so I fabricated a small sample set using a CTE.

```
SQL> set timing on
SQL> with pl_db (country, db_alias, db_logid) as
  2    (select 'US', 'CRD2'      , 'AB1' from dual union all
  3     select 'GR', 'WAZ'       , 'CD2' from dual union all
  4     select 'CN', 'KOL'       , 'EF3' from dual union all
  5     select 'FR', 'DEL'       , 'GH4' from dual union all
  6     select 'HR', 'XBPV'      , 'IJ5' from dual union all
  7     select 'AT', 'PRDO'      , 'KL6' from dual union all
  8     select 'DE', 'ENTERPRISE', 'MN7' from dual
  9    )
 10  select
 11    substr(country, 1, 2) as country,
 12    db_alias              as name,
 13    to_number(regexp_replace(db_logid, '[^0-9]', '')) as wmwhse_id,
 14    to_char(sysdate + 1 - column_value, 'yyyymmdd') as actdate
 15  from pl_db cross join
 16    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 17                        connect by level <= 7
 18                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 19  where db_alias not like '%BPV'
 20    and db_alias not like 'PRDO%'
 21    and db_alias not like 'ENTERPRISE'
 22  order by actdate desc, wmwhse_id asc;

COUNTRY  NAME        WMWHSE_ID ACTDATE
-------- ---------- ---------- --------
US       CRD2                1 20200604
GR       WAZ                 2 20200604
CN       KOL                 3 20200604
FR       DEL                 4 20200604
US       CRD2                1 20200603
GR       WAZ                 2 20200603
CN       KOL                 3 20200603
FR       DEL                 4 20200603
US       CRD2                1 20200602
GR       WAZ                 2 20200602
CN       KOL                 3 20200602
FR       DEL                 4 20200602
US       CRD2                1 20200601
GR       WAZ                 2 20200601
CN       KOL                 3 20200601
FR       DEL                 4 20200601
US       CRD2                1 20200531
GR       WAZ                 2 20200531
CN       KOL                 3 20200531
FR       DEL                 4 20200531
US       CRD2                1 20200530
GR       WAZ                 2 20200530
CN       KOL                 3 20200530
FR       DEL                 4 20200530
US       CRD2                1 20200529
GR       WAZ                 2 20200529
CN       KOL                 3 20200529
FR       DEL                 4 20200529

28 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.09
SQL>
```

Looks quite *fast* to me; try it.

Comment: Thanks for this, helped me greatly! May I ask why table(cast(multiset and sys.odcinumberlist were used in the cross join? I opted to shift the to_char... actdate query directly into the cross join which allowed me to remove those terms and simplify the query.